# Android uiautomator Maintainability/Stability Across Manufacturers

Tags: android, automation

I have successfully configured and installed [Sl4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). I am going to automate with Android using the scripting platform as a base. Many pieces of the functionality that I seek to automate may be exposed through reflection. They may also be manipulated using UI automation. I have considered the use of the [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) and [java reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) methods. I am aware that reflected methods tend to be undocumented, uncertain and unstable across versions. However, they would also allow a certain degree of command line interfacing.

Most important to my endeavor is code maintainability. After reading the `uiautomator` tool documentation and exploring the methods, I am nearly convinced to implement it, as the API looks clean and effective.

My questions are these: what issues, if any, exist with maintaining the `uiautomator` tool as new versions of Android come online? Is the tool API relatively stable across manufacturers, as a general rule, or can "finicky" behavior be anticipated?